# How can I remove an item from a list using a button_click

Tags: c#, list, button

I have a list which I fill with a "foreach", then I want to delete a selected item using a button... I'm doing it like this:

```
private void btn1_Copy1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.MyList.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
       this.MyList.Items.RemoveAt(this.MyList.SelectedIndex);
    }                
}
```

But then, when I press another button to add an item to the list it appears the previous item which I deleted as well.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem curItem = (ComboBoxItem)Games.SelectedItem;
    string SelectedValue = curItem.Content.ToString();


    GamesAdd myOrder = new GamesAdd(SelectedValue, Convert.ToInt16(price.Text), Convert.ToInt16(quant.Text),
                                                    (Convert.ToInt16(price.Text)*Convert.ToInt16(quant.Text)));
    GamesAdd.myList.Add(myOrder);
    MyList.Items.Clear();
    int i=0;
    foreach (var item in GamesAdd.myList)
    {
        i++;
        MyList.Items.Add(i + ". " + item.GameName + " " + item.GameQuant + " x " + item.GamePrice +" " + item.TotalPrice);


    }

}  //This is the add button code
```

Comment: please let us see your add button code

Comment: you could do this do a google search for starters.. there are numerous examples on how to do this on the web start here [How to Many, C# Examples](http://wwww.google.com)  [List<T>.Remove Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) please show more effort !

Comment: do not paste your code as a comment update your question and paste the additional code in your original question

Comment: Add the code to your question. Don't post it in the comments.

Comment: What GamesAdd constructor do? from where it gets data, you will need to remove items from data source as well as from the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have removed the item from the Items list of your combo, not from the myList of the class GameAdd. When you repopulate the list of your combo you readd the previous item still present in the GameAdd static myList

So, supposing the you have the field GameName as unique in your list you could try

```
private void btn1_Copy1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.MyList.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        string itemName = this.MyList.Items[this.MyList.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        string[] gameParts = itemName.Split(' ');
        GamesAdd g = GamesAdd.myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GameName == gameParts[1]);
        GamesAdd.myList.Remove(g);
        this.MyList.Items.RemoveAt(this.MyList.SelectedIndex);
    }                
}
```

For this to work you need to have no spaces in the property of a `GamesAdd` object added to the combo box list items. If this is not the case then add some kind of separator between the strings when you add them to your combobox. For example a point and then split using that point.

A better approach would be to use the `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` and `DataSource` property of the combobox so you could use a property as a key to identify a GamesAdd object without using a cumbersome split